# Series RLC measurement result different with theory

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, passive-networks, series, function-generator

I am measuring the current and voltage in simple RLC circuit:

[image]

However,the result that I measured show big difference with the simulation result using Multisim.

[image]

Why is there are a big difference between 5k-7k measurement value?

For your information I set the function generator output load to high-z. Is it due to this setting?

Comment: Are you sure your multimeter is designed to do ac measurements accurately above 1 kHz? Above 5 kHz?

Comment: Also, if R is 100 ohms and V(R) is 1.141 V (in the 5 kHz case), how do you calculate that the current is 13 mA instead of 11 mA?

Comment: Hi.Thank you for your comment.

I am using the fluke digital multimeter 77 series IV for the measurement.It can measure frequency from 2Hz to 99.99kHz.So I think it is accurate enough for the measurement.

For the current value,it is the actual measurement result using multimeter

Answer (score 2):

Several random things,

1. I think you need to include the (50 ohm?) source impedance in the Function generator.
2. What is the coil resistance? (DC)
3. If the coil is a solenoid beware of near by pieces of metal (conductors, eddy currents)
4. Caps have dissipation (but this will only effect things at high Q, NPO ceramics are good.)
5. Be aware of the capacitance in the probe you are measuring with.

Comment: Yes, it's the 50 ohm output impedance of the signal generator causing this problem - it's reducing the Q of the series tuned circuit and therefore the current aint as big where it should be more resonant.

Comment: thank you for the comment

1. I am using the Hi-Z setting for the function generator output load.Is the setting suitable?

2. I am sorry,I dont have the detail of the coil resistance

3. I am using radial choke inductor for this measurement

4. I am using ceramic capacitor 

5. I am measuring using the multimeter.Is there any probe setting for multimeter?

Comment: Hi @new-learner, I think all the Hi-Z setting does is change the displayed output voltage for the generator.  (I don't think it changes the output circuit.. at least that's how my FG works.)  You can measure the DC resistance of your coil with your DMM.  Not all ceramic caps are made equal.  The more expensive, smaller capacitance NPO ones have low dissipation.  The multi-meter probes are probably the last thing to worry about,  at a guess maybe 30-100 pF of capacitance.  If you change your FG so that it's a perfect voltage source with 50 ohms in series that might help the most with simulation

Comment: Hi @GeorgeHerold

Thank you for your suggestion,
However,I am sorry,I am unclear by 
"If you change your FG so that it's a perfect voltage source with 50 ohms in series that might help the most with simulation"
Do you mean change the output load setting of the FG to 50 ohm?

Comment: @new-learner, So what function generator (FG) do you have?  For the Rigol DG1022 that I use, there is 50 ohms in series with the output.  (A 50 ohm output impedance.)  If I plug this into my scope and look at the output it doesn't change when I switch from Hi-Z to 50 ohms.  What does change is the displayed amplitude of the signal.  The rigol software compensates for the load impedance and adjusts the displayed output voltage.  Play around a bit with yours.  See what happens when you add 50 ohms to ground on the output.  (Know your test gear!)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold.I am using agilent 33522A.
Thank you for your suggestion,I will try it.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I think I get what you mean.
You mean I have to consider the resistor value as 150 Ohm(50+100) for my theory calculation/multisim simulation.
Am I right?

Comment: @new-learner, Exactly!  (plus measure the coil resistance and add that in too.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold thank you very much for your help.

I have another question,how can I know when  I have to set 50 ohm and when I have to set high z?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the parasitic components, like the capacitance of the inductor and the wires.

You can try to repeat the experiment with a larger capacitor, which looks to me like the weakest spot.

Comment: thank you for your comment.

But if i use different value of capacitor,the resonant frequency will change right?